# Is it good to use database connection in websockets PHP?

Tags: php, pdo, ratchet

I am new programmer and I am working on a symfony project which is
a simple social network. So, I want to know is it a bad practice to use database connection directly in ratchet like this:

```
class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface
{
private $pdo;
protected $clients;

public function __construct() {
    $this->pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=symfony_social_network;charset=utf8', 'root', null);;
    $this->clients = [];
}
```

And then to use it in functions like this:

```
public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
    $msgContent = json_decode($msg, true);
    switch ( $msgContent['command'] ) {
        case 'addMessage':
            $this->addMessage($myId, $msgContent, $from);
            break;
        .....
}
```

Add message function:

```
private function addMessage($myId, $msg)
{
    $acceptUser = htmlspecialchars($msg['acceptUser']);
    $dateNow    = htmlspecialchars(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $content    = htmlspecialchars($msg['content']);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO messages (`accept_user`, `send_user`, `content`, `date_added`, `is_delivered`, `is_seen`)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

    if ( isset($this->clients[$acceptUser]) ) {
        $stmt->execute([$acceptUser, $myId, $content, $dateNow, 1, 0]);
    }else {
        $stmt->execute([$acceptUser, $myId, $content, $dateNow, 0, 0]);
    }
    return $this->pdo->lastInsertId();
}
```

Or is better to use AJAX. Then to use ZMQ to send message to websocket and then websocket to send to a specific user. Something like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/addMessage", methods={"POST"})
 */
public function addMessage(Request $request) {

        ....

        $context   = new \ZMQContext(1);
        $socket    = $context->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH);
        $socket->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");
        $socket->send(json_encode($arr));
}
```

Comment: AJAX does not negate the need for a database connection.

Comment: Yes, but I want to know which is the best way to do this. Database connection in websocket or usual AJAX.

Comment: AJAX has no database connection, neither does a web socket. You have to establish a database connection in your server-side code.